# The file selection window does not open vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I just need to open a window with a file selection. Why doesn't it open? here is my code. Thank you!

```
<input type="file" @change="imageFileNew" class="form-control" >
imageFileNew(e) {
        var files = e.target.files[0]
        this.newCategory.image = files
 },
```

Comment: The problem is not is the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, that the problem is not inside this code. But if you are using any custom input like this

[image]

Then your  tag should look like this

```
<input type="file" class="file-loader__input" @change="provide_user_input" onclick="this.value = null">
```